# NLTK regex parser's output has changed. Unable to parse phrases like verb followed by a noun

Tags: regex, nltk

I have written a piece of code to parse the action items from a troubleshooting doc.
I want to extract phrases that start with a verb and end with a noun.

It was working as expected earlier (a month ago). But on running against the same input as earlier, its missing some action items that it was catching previously.

I haven't changed the code. Has something changed from nltk or punkt side that may be affecting my results?

Please help me figure what needs to be changed to make it run as earlier.

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
#One time downloads
#nltk.download('punkt')
#nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
#nltk.download('wordnet')

custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer()


def process_content(x):
    try:
        #sent_tag = []
        act_item = []
        for i in x:
            print('tokenized = ',i)
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
            print(words)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
            print('tagged = ',tagged)
            #sent_tag.append(tagged)
            #print('sent= ',sent_tag)
            #chunking
            chunkGram = r"""ActionItems: {<VB.>+<JJ.|CD|VB.|,|CC|NN.|IN|DT>*<NN|NN.>+}"""

            chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
            chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged)
            print(chunked)
            for subtree in chunked.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'ActionItems'):
                print('Filtered chunks= ',subtree)
                ActionItems = ' '.join([w for w, t in subtree.leaves()])
                act_item.append(ActionItems)
                chunked.draw()           
            
        return act_item

    except Exception as e:
        #print(str(e))
        return str(e)


res = 'replaced rev 6 aeb with a rev 7 aeb. configured new board and regained activity. tuned, flooded and calibrated camera. scanned fi rst patient with no issues. made new backups. replaced aeb board and completed setup. however, det 2 st ill not showing any counts. performed all necessary tests and the y passed . worked with tech support to try and resolve the issue. we decided to order another board due to lower rev received. camera is st ill down.'

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(res)
tag = process_content(tokenized)
```

With the input as shared in the code, **earlier**, the following action items were being  parsed:

['replaced rev 6 aeb', 'configured new board', 'regained activity', 'tuned , flooded and calibrated camera', 'scanned fi rst patient', 'made new backups', 'replaced aeb board', 'completed setup', 'det 2 st ill', 'showing any counts', 'performed all necessary tests and the y', 'worked with tech support']

But **now**, only these are coming up:

['regained activity', 'tuned , flooded and calibrated camera', 'completed setup', 'det 2 st ill', 'showing any counts']

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this by replacing JJ. with JJ|JJR|JJS

So my chunk is defined as :
`chunkGram = r"""ActionItems: {<VB.>+<JJ|JJR|JJS|CD|NN.|CC|IN|VB.|,|DT>*<NN|NN.>+}"""`

I dont understand this change in behavior.
Dot (.) was a really good way of using all modifiers on a POS